# Read image files with QImageReader using QtConcurrent

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, thread-safety

I am trying to use QImageReader to read portions of an image file at a time (per Tile), so that for very large images they are not read into memory from disk until they need to be displayed.

It seems liek I am running into some thread safety issues.

This is what I currently have:

```
#include "rastertile.h"

QMutex RasterTile::mutex;
RasterTile::RasterTile()
{
}

//RasterTile::RasterTile(QImageReader *reader, int nBlocksX, int nBlocksY, int xoffset, int yoffset, int nXBlockSize, int nYBlockSize)
RasterTile::RasterTile(QString filename, int nBlocksX, int nBlocksY, int xoffset, int yoffset, int nXBlockSize, int nYBlockSize)

    : Tile(nBlocksX, nBlocksY, xoffset, yoffset, nXBlockSize, nYBlockSize)
{
        this->reader = new QImageReader(filename);
        connect(&watcher,SIGNAL(finished()),this,SLOT(updateSceneSlot()));
}


void RasterTile::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,QWidget *widget)
{
    if(image.isNull())
    {
        TilePainter=painter;
        TileOption=option;
        TileWidget=widget;
        future = QtConcurrent::run(this, &RasterTile::LoadTilePixmap);
        watcher.setFuture(future);

    }else
    {
        QRectF imageRect = image.rect();
        painter->drawImage(imageRect, image);
    }

}

QImage RasterTile::LoadTilePixmap()
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);

    QImage img(nBlockXSize, nBlockYSize, QImage::Format_RGB32);

    QRect rect(tilePosX*nBlockXSize, tilePosY*nBlockYSize, nBlockXSize, nBlockYSize);

    reader->setClipRect(rect);
    reader->read(&img);
    if(reader->error())
    {
        qDebug("Not null error");
        qDebug()<<"Error string is: "<<reader->errorString();
    }
    return img;

}
```

So this is basically instantiating a new reader for each tile, and update the "image" variable of the superclass, which I can then paint.

This seems to give me a lot of errors from the reader, which simply say "Unable to read image data"

I think this is probably something to do with many tiles accessing the same file, but I dont know how to prove that, or fix it.

I think Qt uses libjpeg and libpng and whatever else to read various image formats.

Comment: How many is "many tiles"? The practical limit on the number of threads is usually fairly small.

Comment: Make sure a simple single-threaded program can load the tiles via QImageReader. I'd also create the QImageReader on the stack, in LoadTilePixmap(). If you make LoadPixmap a free function and pass everything as argument, you could avoid any synchronization issues. Why the mutex? It is static? That'd limit the tiles loaded at a time to 1...

Comment: the number of tiles could be over 1000 total, but only a few loading at a time. Whichever tiles are visible for the first time in the viewer are the only ones that this will kick off new threads for. The mutex was static, yes. I was attempting to keep the QImageReader from having more than one accessing the the file on disk at once. I tried to put the QImageReader on the stack, but got the same results as having it on heap and passed in.

Comment: Could you please post the definition of `RasterTile` and `Tile`? It would make it easier for us to make experiments.

Comment: RasteTile is what is posted. I will see if I can add Tile. It was basically just something extending a QGraphicsItem

Answer (score 2):

Check out the source code of [QImageReader](http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid913580E1AA4121B545E6658A372096007AF6E571.aspx?s=mdef%3ainsert).

You will get *"Unable to read image data"* when the reader returns **InvalidDataError**.

If you also read the explanation of [InvalidDataError](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qimagereader.html#ImageReaderError-enum) QT Doc says that

> The image data was invalid, and
>   QImageReader was unable to read an
>   image from it. The can happen if the
>   image file is damaged.

So probably your file is corrupt.

Comment: I wondered about that, but I am able to read the file from other places, and if I take out the concurrency in this code and just try to read each tile serially.

Answer (score 2):

I see two potential problems here.

1. This is not your real problem but my be an issue with small tiles later. `future` is set *after* the thread is started. This may cause trouble, if the thread finishes, before `future` is set correctly. (Not 100% sure about this, but lets say... 85%, and I believe this is very unlikely to happen)
2. `paint` can be called really often. I believe your problem is that it is called the second time, before your reading thread finished. This would cause another thread trying to read the tile while the first one is still reading it. Thy will even try to use the same instance of QImageReader at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding in:

```
if (reader->canRead())
    reader->read(&img);
else
    qDebug() << "Could not read from device";
```

It may not help much but according to the documentation canRead: Returns true if an image can be read for the device (i.e., the image format is supported, and the device seems to contain valid data); otherwise returns false.

Answer (score 0):

You could try another way of creating threads for reading the tiles.

Create a myReaderObject as subclass from QObject.

In your main thread constructor create a member QThread object:

```
m_workerthread=new QThread();
m_workerthread->start();
```

For reading a tile do

```
myReaderObject *reader=new myReaderObject();
reader->moveToThread(m_workerthread);
connect ( reader, SIGNAL(myFinishSignal() , ...
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(reader,"read", Qt::AutoConnection);
```

Your myReaderObject then of course needs a read method and a myFinishSignal signal